# How to add a word before or after some string lines

Tags: php, http

Using PHP, i have a list of names , I want to add this at the first of each lines:

```
'http://
```

And add this one to the last of each line :

```
' ,
```

Example >>

I have this :

```
john
michel 
hosein
ali
```

And i want this :

```
'http://john' , 
'http://michel ' , 
'http://hosein' , 
'http://ali' ,
```

Is there any code to do this for me ?

Comment: What should happen if one of the names happens to contain an apostrophe?

Comment: `$var = "'http://" . $name . "',"` - Note there are double quotes surrounding single quotes here.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol none of my names contain apostrophe. they just have Domain TLD , like .com and etc

Comment: are the names in an array ??

Comment: Do you want really these strings or you want to create an array and need some regex to use in your IDE?

Comment: @BhaveshGangani yes, the names are in array .

Comment: @enenen i have the names , i just want to put them into array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code will help:

```
<?
$lineStart= "'http://";
$lineEnd  = "' , ";
$names    = array("john", "michel", "hosein", "ali"); //array with names

for ($i=0; $i<count($names) ; $i++)                  //echo as many times as the number of names in a string
{
    echo $lineStart.$names[$i].$lineEnd."<br>";      //just string concatenation
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks , its perfect , but  is there any way to put the names easily ? like the list ?

Comment: is there any way to put the names easily ? like the simple list ?

Comment: You can add names into the array like this : $names    = array("john", "michel", "hosein", "ali" , "another name");

Comment: thanks , but let me Explain a little . i have a simple TXT list of some domain, now i just want to copy and paste the list into the code, and the number of this list is more than 100000 item! so i can't put them easily into the array . i have to just copy and paste the list into the code and get my result .

Comment: Try this :  
<?  
$lineStart= "'http://";  
$lineEnd  = "' , ";  
$file = fopen("domain_list.txt","r");  

while(! feof($file))  
  {  
  echo $lineStart. fgets($file).$lineEnd."<br>";  
  }  

fclose($file);  
?>

Answer (score 4):

if your lines are in an array, you could use something like this:

```
$out = array_map(function($item) {
    return "'http://{$item}', ";
}, $data);
```

if they aren't you have to use explode(or an preg_split) to put them into an array

Comment: how can i use this dear ?

Comment: As I understand he has the string only. It's not an array. So he should use some regex in his IDE to create a PHP array from simple string with names and newline characters (`\n`). Unless I'm not mistaken...

Comment: `$data = array('john', 'michael', ...)` or if you have a multiline string `$data = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $string)`

Answer (score 1):

For example your values are in an array named `$array` and you want to save the new format in an array named `$new_array` you can try like this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $new_array[] = "'http://".$value."' ,";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $ary = array("john", "michel", "hosein", "ali");
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($ary as $val) 
        $newArray[] = "'http://" .$val. "', ";
?>
```

To get the names list from the file,

**EDIT :**

```
<?php
    $ary = file("inputfile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($ary as $val) {
        $newArray[] = "'http://".$val."', ";
    }
?>
```

Here, the **inputfile.txt** contains the names line by line.

ex.

```
john
michel 
hosein
ali
```

Comment: hmmmm okk. happy coding ... :)

Comment: is there any way to put the names easily ? like the list ?

Comment: put the names means ? you mean push value in the array ?

Comment: yeah . let me Explain. i have a simple TXT list of some domain, now i just want to copy and paste the list into the code, and the number of this list is more than 100000 item! so i can't put them easily into the array . i have to just copy and paste the list into the code and get my result .

Comment: Very Thanks , you helped me alot :X have nice day :x